# C++ Stop Preprocessor Macro Expansion

Tags: c++, c++11, preprocessor, preprocessor-directive

Here is my example code https://godbolt.org/z/VKgKik

```
#define delete MyCustomDelete(__FILE__, __LINE__), delete

#define CAT(X,Y) CAT2(X,Y)
#define CAT2(X,Y) X##Y
#define CAT_3(X,Y,Z) CAT(X,CAT(Y,Z))    


class A {
    A() = CAT_3(de,le,te);
};
```

The godbolt example is setup to display the preprocessor output. The goal is that at the end of the preprocessor pass i want the output code to be

```
class A {
    A() = delete;
};
```

currently "ThisShouldNotshowUp" is displayed there instead. I thought the use of the ## operator would stop the preprocessor from reexpanding but it did not.

I realize removing the "#define delete" would solve the problem but I need this define there. The reason I have created a macro with the same name as delete is because I want to be able to track the news and deletes, and If a memory leak occurs I can see what line of code aloced it. This macro thus means I can continue to use the keyword delete in my code and the File and line numbers get filled in for free. As far as i know there is no other way to achieve this functionailty except by defined a delete macro. This is the crux of the problem. The delete macro has given me a powerful debug tool however it has removed a useful language feature for me to use.

Comment: 1. `CAT_2` and `_helper` are never used. 2. `#define delete` makes the program ill-formed; defining keywords as macro names is not allowed.

Comment: I know it is technically against the standard but is there a hack i can do to get it to work? Lets assume removing the #define delete is not possible

Comment: Looks like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me. Why do you need this?

Comment: updated to hopefully address your concern

Comment: "*I realize removing the "#define delete" would solve the problem but I need this define there*" - why? Is there a reason you are not simply overloading the [new operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new) and [delete operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_delete) instead?

Comment: @RemyLebeau I assume the reason is that once inside `operator delete`, you no longer have access to the source file & line where the `delete` expression is.

Comment: @Angew probably so, though that can be solved by having the operator extract the return address from the call stack and then compare that to the compiler's debug output to figure out the source file and line number.

Comment: @RemyLebeau sorry for the late response but your assumption is correct. The issue with the solution you propose is that I cant have the file and line number print out during the execution. I have a setup such that when i shutdown my program it runs my memory leak checker and if it finds any leaks prints out the file/line number of the new call. I have already overloaded the new/delete operator to take in file/line number, I use the macro to ensure the user doesn't have to add __LINE__, __FILE__ to every new/delete call

Comment: @lufthansa747 "*The issue with the solution you propose is that I cant have the file and line number print out during the execution.*" - you can, if your compiler saves the debug info in a file that you can load at runtime.

Comment: fair, was trying to avoid that type of solution. But its a valid approach. The macro approach seemed a little cleaner and easier to me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're trying to do is not possible, as [Michael Karcher's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56046102/1782465) states: `#define delete` already makes the program ill-formed, and expanding an object-like macro (outside its own expansion) cannot be avoided.

However, for your particular use case detailed in the question, a workaround is possible. You could put your `#define delete` into a header file (let's call it `debug_delete.hxx`), like this:

```
#ifdef delete
# undef delete
#endif
#define delete MyCustomDelete(__FILE__, __LINE__), delete
```

Then, create another header file (let's call it `normal_delete.hxx`):

```
#ifdef delete
# undef delete
#endif
```

Note in particular that there is no mechanism in these headers to prevent multiple inclusion; in fact, we want them includable an arbitrary number of times.

Then, wrap code which must use `= delete;` in appropriate `#include` directives:

```
class A {
#include "normal_delete.hxx"
    A() = delete;
#include "debug_delete.hxx"
    ~A() { delete p; }
};
```

(Yes, it's ugly, but what you're doing is sort of ugly in the first place, so ugly code may be required to make it work).

Answer (score 6):

You have no chance in creating a preprocessing token that is the name of an object-like macro from expanding a macro. The relevant section of n3337 is `[cpp.rescan]`. I quote a shortened part of the first paragraph in it.

> After all parameters in the replacement list have been substituted and `#` and `##` processing has taken place [...]. Then the resulting preprocessing token sequence is rescanned [...] for more macro names to replace.

Nonwithstanding the problem, that `delete` is technically forbidden to be a macro name, there is no way to prevent the macro name to be recognized while rescanning.

You probably mixed up the fact that `##` operator does use it's *parameters* without expansion with the idea that the *result* of `##` doesn't undergo macro expansion.

Comment: macros that include their own name do not reexpand it on their own. they're doing it here because he passes it through a number of other macro expansions in the nested CATs. his macro doesn't expand to "ThisShouldNotshowUp", but "MyCustomDelete("main.c", 10), delete". if the macro had been "#define delete delete" it would not loop in any way, and would just leave "delete". He certainly can't special case a token macro to expand differently however. If he were using a function like macro, something might be possible, but that wouldn't capture the array deletes

Comment: @MichaelSpeer Even this `delete` does not re-expand; the problem is not in any looping, it's in `MyCustomDelete` not being syntactically valid where `delete` is used to mark a function deleted.

Comment: Most definitely. I just wanted to ensure that the information on how macros expand was accurate.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you want to use a macro so you can turn on and off your delete tracking. If you're only using this on your source, and not trying to rig it up to transform existing C++, you could use a function-like macro in order to effect the optional tracking that you desire.

```
#define TRACK_DELETES 0
#if TRACK_DELETES
  #define DELETE( a ) \
    do { MyCustomDelete( __FILE__, __LINE__ ); delete (a); } while (0)
  #define DELETEALL( a ) \
    do { MyCustomDelete( __FILE__, __LINE__ ); delete [] (a); } while (0)
#else
  #define DELETE( a ) do { delete (a) ; } while(0)
  #define DELETEALL( a ) do { delete [] (a) ; } while(0)
#endif

int main(){

  DELETE( A );
  DELETEALL( B );

  return 0;
}
```

See if this does what you want with TRACK_DELETES set to 0 or 1 under `gcc -E`.

You'll want to leave the bare `delete` keyword alone so it can be used appropriately.

Comment: The issue with this is it require the coder to remember to use this delete macro